# JavaScript - Generating .SRT file

Tags: javascript, blob, subtitle

I made a script to edit my subtitles in my browser. not in text editors etc.. so i did everything and i am at the final stage of it, when i click the button 'save' to download my edited version, My browser automatically downloads the SRT file as expected, But however the subtitle is shown as 'Little Square Boxes' instead of the arabic text i wrote and edited..

What i see on VLC Video Player:

[image: SCR1]

What i have in my SRT File:

```
1
00:00:05,796 --> 00:00:06,888 
چیرۆكم پێ بڵێ

2
00:00:07,048 --> 00:00:08,265 
چیرۆكم پێ بڵێ

3
00:00:08,424 --> 00:00:09,846 
چیرۆكم پێ بڵێ
```

Code used to generate edited version of subtitle:

```
    // Function to download data to a file
function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}
```

And then:

```
download(all_str,"anyth.srt","text/html")
```

The string `all_str`is my new edited version of the subtitles.. all separated by new lines, just like the text editor version

The subtitle works with english and other languages except arabic

Things i have done to fix this:

- Changed `text/html` to `text/plain` and `text/plain utf-8` and `text/plain charset=utf-8` but didn't work
- Changed VLC Player's Encoding type from Universal to utf8 but didn't work

I think this has to do something with the encoding type, something i missed or don't know? please fill me in

Comment: I know nothing about the subtitles but the correct `Content-Type` value is `text/plain; charset=utf-8` (note the `; charset=` bit).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, like this? `text/plain charset=utf-8`.. it doesn't work

Comment: As long as you save the downloaded file, neither the MIME type nor the encoding matter. The MIME type is useful for the browser to know how to handle the downloaded file: save, render it itself or save it in a temporary file and open it with a certain application. The encoding is useful only if the browser renders the file itself.

Comment: @axiac, i think its the encoding issue,, because it works with English text

Comment: Is the downloaded file correctly rendered when you open it with a plain text editor (the same editor you use to check the original `.srt` file)?

Comment: @axiac, yes.. it appears exactly as expected.. but not in the video player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing everything right, However most of our current operating systems run on Windows-1256..
I have tested your code with this unicode, it works with Arabic and Persian:

Just change:

```
text/plain;charset=windows-1256
```

Comment: Needless to say, [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) may not be common in countries that do not use the Arabic script or in operating systems that are not shipped by Microsoft. Plus just *declaring* the encoding does not change the actual bytes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález.. I am talking about middle eastern countries.. where we live— and plus seems like it solved the issue